# DocuSign | Radiobuttons and Checkboxes

Tags: json, checkbox, radio-button, docusignapi, docusignconnect

How does it look like in JSON if I want to have radio buttons for Yes / No,

Then if one answers Yes,

a checkbox on the Telephone / Email / Mobile shall be prompted?

SEE IMAGE HERE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvLuV.png

Here is how I am seeing it, but not sure if correct:

```
      "checkboxTabs": [
        {
          "conditionalParentLabel": "RADIOGROUP",
          "conditionalParentValue": "Yes_1",
          "anchorString": "\\XL1\\",
          "tabLabel": "Landline",
          "tabGroupLabels": [
            "checkboxgroup1"    
          ]
        },
        {
          "conditionalParentLabel": "RADIOGROUP",
          "conditionalParentValue": "Yes_1",
          "anchorString": "\\XE1\\",
          "tabLabel": "Email",
          "tabGroupLabels": [
            "checkboxgroup1"              
          ]
        },
        {
          "conditionalParentLabel": "RADIOGROUP",
          "conditionalParentValue": "Yes_1",
          "anchorString": "\\XM1\\",
          "tabLabel": "Mobile",
          "tabGroupLabels": [
            "checkboxgroup1"
          ]
        }           
      ],
      "radioGroupTabs": [
        {
          "groupName": "RADIOGROUP",
          "radios": [
            {
              "anchorString": "\\XY1\\",
              "value": "Yes_1"
            },
            {
              "anchorString": "\\XN1\\",                  
              "value": "No_1"
            }
          ]
        }           
      ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [conditional fields](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/conditional-fields/). You would need to set the conditionalParentLabel and conditionalParentValue fields on the checkbox tabs so that the value for conditionalParentLabel matches the value for tabLabel in the parent tab. In this case the parent tab is the radio button. You would also need to set conditionalParentValue to "on." There is an example of what this json would look like here https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/conditional-fields/

Comment: Updated my Question with the block of JSON code. Is that valid? :/

Comment: That JSON looks correct. I'm not sure if that image corresponds with this JSON but it looks like two sets of checkbox tabs instead of one radio group. The radio tabs appear more like circles.